# I am looking for storing particular field in particular shard in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

By routing we can allocate particular file/doc/json in particular shard which make it easy to extract data.
But I am thinking as would it be possible to store particular field of json file in particular  shard.
for eg:
i had three field : username , message and time. I had created 3 shard for indexing.
Now i want that
username is stored in one shard , message in another shard and time in another shard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. The whole document (the JSON doc) will be stored on one shard. If you want to do what you describe, then you should split the data up into separate docs and then you can route them differently.

As for the reasoning, imagine there was a username query which matched document5. If document5 was spread over many shards, these would all have to be queried to get the other parts of document5 back to compile the results. Imagine further a complex AND query across different fields, there would be a lot of traffic (and waiting) to find out if both fields match to compute if the document was a hit or not.

Comment: that means in elasticsearch it cant achieve this. what I was thinking if this would be possible then searching performance will be improve if searching needs to be performed on particular field.

Comment: I don't understand how you think searching would be faster if you split the document up. Imagine we are searching for `username = "john"`. With your way, you have only 1 shard doing all the computing. With the elasticsearch way, all three shards share the search load. How would your way be faster?

Comment: As far as retrieval is concerned it would be clumsy process but searching would be performed on one field otherwise if it go on looking for all shard which contain different field

Comment: I don't think you understand the benefits of a distributed system are. This is **why** elasticsearch was created, as it is distributed out-of-the-box. The idea is to **distribute** the computation of a task (e.g. searching for username starts with "foo") across many computers to do it faster.

Comment: My mistake I had not though about that distribute searching as well as while it search for data we can made it to search in particular field

Comment: I hope I was able to help in some way. If I did, please consider accepting/upvoting the answer. If you feel like you have more questions feel free to post another.